# Passing coroutines is forbidden, use tasks explicitly. Only raise on Apple M1

Tags: python, python-asyncio, apple-m1, aiogram

I have problem when try run simple async func in aioschedule and aiogram
I use Apple M1

```
import aioschedule
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

TOKEN = 'token here'
bot = Bot(TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

async def hello():
    print('Hello World')

async def scheduler():
    """Планувальник задач"""
    try:
        aioschedule.every().minute.do(hello)

        while True:
            await aioschedule.run_pending()
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
    except Exception as error:
        logger.error(error)

async def on_startup(_):
    """Запуск планувальника задач при старті бота"""
    asyncio.create_task(scheduler())
    logger.info('TelegramBot running...')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=on_startup)
    except Exception as err:
        logger.error(err)
```

After launching `sheduler` is started but when it launch func `hello` raise error

```
2023-03-17 16:18:15,076 [ERROR] - __main__ - scheduler(180) - Passing coroutines is forbidden, use tasks explicitly.
/Users/emojiestore/programs/GitHub/Health-KPI/telegram_service/main.py:180: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Job.run' was never awaited
  logger.error(error)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

But when I run this code on my old MacBook on Intel - all work correct

Comment: This is likely due to a change in Python version, not a change in architecture.

Comment: Ie, don't pass `hello` itself to `do`, but a task created from `hello`.